# Unable to install build-dep for Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64

Tags: apt, kernel, compiling

I am using 22.04.2.  Why is linux-signed-hwe-5.19 being picked instead of the currently installed kernel version?  The impact of this has been when I update my target kernel with my modified source, it breaks the ability to download any packages as I have conflicts.  Any advice would be appreciated.

```
alex@alex-Virtual-Machine:~$ sudo apt build-dep linux linux-image-$(uname -r)
    Reading package lists... Done'
    Picking 'linux-signed-hwe-5.19' as source package instead of 'linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic'
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree... Done
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 builddeps:linux-signed-hwe-5.19 : Depends: linux-image-unsigned-5.19.0-40-generic (= 5.19.0-40.41~22.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                                   Depends: linux-generate-hwe-5.19 (= 5.19.0-40.41~22.04.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
    
alex@alex-Virtual-Machine:~$ uname -mrs
    Linux 5.19.0-40-generic x86_64
    
alex@alex-Virtual-Machine:~$ apt policy build-essential
    build-essential:
      Installed: 12.9ubuntu3
      Candidate: 12.9ubuntu3
      Version table:
     *** 12.9ubuntu3 500
            500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: try `sudo apt install linux-image-unsigned-5.19.0-40-generic linux-generate-hwe-5.19` to add the missing dependency manually. Then run `sudo apt build-dep linux linux-image-$(uname -r)` again

Comment: Thank you Arjun, but I do not understand why it is "Picking" a different version in the first place, instead of following the kernel version I just installed?

Comment: I did try your suggestion as well, but it ends in an error.    This is a clean install of 22.04 LTS. alex@alex-Virtual-Machine:~$ sudo apt install linux-image-unsigned-5.19.0-40-generic linux-generate-hwe-5.19
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-generate-hwe-5.19
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-generate-hwe-5.19'

Comment: Ran into this same problem today :|  "apt-get build-dep linux linux-image-unsigned-$(uname -r)" results in:

"E: Unable to find a source package for linux-image-unsigned-5.19.0-32-generic"

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this workaround below

> sudo apt-get build-dep linux linux-image-unsigned-$(uname -r)

"-unsigned" is added extra.
Originally answered here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75695258/how-to-fix-broken-packages-of-linux-unsigned-image